# Does a $k$D sphere maximized the volume/surface ratio?

Tags: geometry

Does $\{\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R} \mid ||\vec{x}|| \leq 1\}$ have the minimum surface among the shapes with the same volume?

Comment: Nice question! Do you mean $\mathbb{R}^n$?